# Android ListViewItem layout with the button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am quite new to Android. I want to add two buttons in listview item template at the bottom right corner.

Right now I have such layout:
[image: existing layout]

And the code:

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/icon"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/secondLine"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="26dip"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
>     android:ellipsize="marquee"
>     android:singleLine="true"
>     android:text="Details"
>     android:textSize="12sp" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
>     android:gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:text="Test title"
>     android:textSize="16sp" />
> ```

What I want to achieve is to add two button in the bottom right corner, something like this:

[image: expected]

I also tried to put `RelativeLayout` into `LinearLayout` and then add one more child `LinearLayout` with the button aligning it horizontaly, but listview item row doesn't show them at all.

Comment: put the code with parent layout..

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: I am asking about the row layout code in which you want to show buttons

Comment: Are you using a Custom Adapter?  Try encapsulating the `ImageView`, and the two other `TextViews` into one single `LinearLayout` and the two `Buttons` in another `LinearLayout`.  Make a `RelativeLayout` as a parent to both and position them using `layout_below` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you need the buttons at the bottom right of each list item.  If so, the below will work for you:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height= "fill_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/FirstLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height= "fill_parent">
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/icon"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/secondLine"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="26dip"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
               android:ellipsize="marquee"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:text="Details"
               android:textSize="12sp" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:text="Test title"
               android:textSize="16sp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/SecondLayout"
         android:layout_below="@+id/FirstLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height= "fill_parent">
              <Button 
                  android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                  android:text ="Button Two"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
              <Button 
                  android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                  android:text ="Button One"
                  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnTwo"/>
      </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below for your desired layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DADADA" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ItemMainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Icon"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Details" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/HorizontalSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ItemMainContainer"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/HorizontalSeparator"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delete"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/Separator"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button2"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Separator"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delete"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Button1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the result. [image: screenshot]

Change the assets accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, You are looking for alignment adjustment of your component. You have already used **android:layout_alignParentXXXX**, and **layout_above/below** attributes. 
Please do some changes, you will get the desired.

I have checked the below code, this may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/lin1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
// here place you existing code
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Description"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Button2"/>

     <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Button1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Test title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
       android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Modify the code w.r.t your need